# Unable to read cookie in UIWebview browser with document.cookie

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, cookies, uiwebview

I have an iOS app where I am loading html content inside a webview. The html is a login page wherein the user credentials are sent to the server via ajax and an authentication success/failure response is received. Now, the response contains a cookie (in the `Set-Cookie` header field) which I can capture on the Objective-C side like so,

```
NSDictionary* headers = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields]; 
NSString *strCookies = [headers valueForKey:@"Set-Cookie"]; 
NSLog(@"cookies -> %@", strCookies);
```

The same response also contains a `responseText` which I use inside the browser:

```
Ajax("/login", "POST", { onsuccess : function(response){ 
       /* Do HTML stuff with response */ }  
});
```

Now I need the cookie to make further ajax requests (after the login page). However, the cookie is not set inside the webview browser. Looking for `document.cookie` returns an empty string. I can print all the response headers using `xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()` but I cannot access the `Set-Cookie` field in the xhr object.

How can the cookie be set inside the webview? Or I have no choice but to make all ajax requests via Obj-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the cookie in the request that you send to the webview.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:yourURL];
[request setValue:yourCookie forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
```

This could be done in the UIWebview delegate shouldStartLoadWithRequest